# Fullcalendar - Show event in calendar from start date to end date

Tags: fullcalendar

So, I want to display the events from the calendar from Start Date to end date.

Ex, if my start date is 21 December 2015 and my end date is 26 December 2015 I want my event to be rendered on all days, not just from 21 to 25.

[image]

I put a image as an example.

LE: The start date / end date are taken from `event` variable

Comment: If these are "all day" events, the event will end at 12AM on 12/26/2015 which may not be what you expected. You could extend the end to 12/27/2015 (meaning it goes through all day of 12/26/2015)

Comment: Yes, they are all day events. Well, if I extend the end to 12/27/2015 it's the same thing. I goes all the day through 12/26/2015 but doesn't go to 12/27/2015. I need to render the event from 21 to 26 and not only from 21 to 25.

Comment: Yeah, it wouldn't render on 12/27/2015. Another approach is to set the end time to '2015-12-26 23:59:59'

Comment: And disable "all days"?

Comment: If you didn't set 'allDayDefault', or 'allDay' on the event object, specifying a time on the 'end' should work by itself

Answer (score 0):

Setting (programatically) the datetime to `26 December 23:59:00` resolves the problem. When you pick `26 December` as a startDate, you actually pick `26 December 00:00:00`, which comes exactly after the end of `25 December` as you see on the `p:schedule`